# SQL Long to Wide Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query that gives results in the following format:

```
+------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|  ID  | Historical Event | Historical Event Date | Historical Date Status | Historical Date Reason |
+------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 1234 | Referral         | 12/31/18              | Active                 | Vendor Request         |
| 1234 | Evaluation       | 1/2/19                | Inactive               | Ineligible             |
| 1234 | Referral         | 2/1/19                | Active                 | Recommendation         |
| 1235 | Referral         | 1/1/17                | Active                 | No reason required     |
| 1235 | Waitlist         | 1/3/17                | Active                 | Approved               |
| 1235 | Waitlist         | 1/5/17                | Inactive               | Removed                |
| 1236 | Referral         | 1/3/19                | Active                 | Hold                   |
| 1236 | Referral         | 1/5/19                | Active                 | Approved               |
+------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

EDIT: Taking these above results as a temporary table I could then join back into the main query, how can I manipulate the above table to get the desired output below?

I need to be able to refer to historical events to determine if current events are valid to be counted. For example:

- if more than one referral in a calendar year and intermediate updates are "Referral" or "Evaluation" with reason "Ineligible" then both are counted in the same year
- if more than one referral in multiple years and intermediate updates show "Referral" "Ineligible" then both are counted in their respective years
- if a Referral is marked "Hold" it is not a valid Referral date

so, the 1234 id, which has two referral dates in two years with an intervening status of Ineligible should have both 12/31/18 and 2/1/19 as referral dates

example output for more advanced logic would be something like

```
+------+-----------------+---------------+--------+---------------------+
|  ID  | Referral Valid? | Referral Date | Status |       Reason        |
+------+-----------------+---------------+--------+---------------------+
| 1234 | Y               | 12/31/18      | Active | Vendor Request      |
| 1234 | Y               | 2/1/19        | Active | Recommendation      |
| 1235 | Y               | 1/1/17        | Active | No reason required  |
| 1236 | Y               | 1/5/19        | Active | Approved            |
+------+-----------------+---------------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: How big is the table involved?

Comment: What would really help here is sample data and desired output for the sample data. Posting nothing but the results of your current query (and not even that query) is pretty useless.

Comment: the results of the original query are very long, maybe 23k lines. The original data that goes into the query in spread across about 50 different tables and very complex. I assumed the solution would involve using the above sample output as a temporary table.

Comment: Why do you include the 1236 Hold record in your desired results?

Comment: Results could either include all events with the Y/N or could just be the Y events. I was trying to make the conditional logic more clear.

Comment: What if you just added a `WHERE` clause like so > `WHERE HistoricalEvent = 'Referral' AND HistoricalDateReason <> 'Hold'`... ?